# Method not returning as True

Tags: python, methods

I am trying to return True from the isCorrect method to the correctMessage method. But correctMessage does not run right due to isCorrect outputting 
"function isCorrect at 0x000000"

```
def correctMessage(isCorrect, tryAnswer, questionAnswer):
    if isCorrect is True:
        return print("Yes! You answered \"", 
                     str(tryAnswer), "\" and the answer was " + questionAnswer)

def isCorrect(tryAnswer, questionAnswer):
    if str(tryAnswer).lower() == questionAnswer:
        return True
    return False
```

What can I do for this to be evaluated correctly?

Comment: You should use `isCorrect()` (with parentheses) to actually _call_ the function.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers below if we have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *call* `isCorrect`, you tested if the function itself was `True`. Add parens and pass the two arguments `isCorrect` requires.

Side-notes: You didn't need `if` with two returns in `isCorrect`. `return str(tryAnswer).lower() == questionAnswer` would do the exact same thing faster.

Similarly, testing `if x is True:` is ugly, and almost always wrong, just test `if x:` unless the value `True` is *really* important and different from all other truthy values (in this case, it's the only truthy possibility, so it's faster and more Pythonic to just do `if isCorrect(...):`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call isCorrect with the parameters you wish to pass to it.
You're currently checking to see if the physical function isCorrect is equal to True - which it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
def correctMessage(isCorrect, tryAnswer, questionAnswer):
    if isCorrect(tryAnswer, quenstionAnswer):
        print("Yes! You answered \"", str(tryAnswer), "\" and the answer was " + questionAnswer)

def isCorrect(tryAnswer, questionAnswer):
    return str(tryAnswer).lower() == questionAnswer:
```